# list view checkboxes to update with app.config entry at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I have app.config file in my win form application. In my design I have a listview, in which checkbox property is set to true.

What I want is that I should be able to populate the list with the values entered in app.config file.

If yes, I request you to point me in right direction on how to structure app.config to suit my need.

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with? Reading the value from your app.config? Or applying the value to your checkbox?

Comment: Moreover, what section from your app.config do you want to populate the dropdown with? app settings? connection strings?...

Comment: @user65439 I would like to read the data from app.config and populate the same to list view with checkboxes while displaying the form

Comment: @Gonzix:its not a drop down..

Comment: doesn't matter the type of list... they are both data binding controls... the thing is WHAT you want to take from app.config

Answer (score 1):

Add key values to your `app.config` as below:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Key1" value="Value1" />
    <add key="Key2" value="Value2" />
    <add key="Key3" value="Value3" />
</appSettings>
```

then read from appSettings with `ConfigurationManager`:

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"]
```

and build a dictionary (or list or another datastructure):

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("Key1", value);
```

and bind to your listBox:

```
listBox1.DataSource = dic.SelectMany(d => d.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: @vysakh, the explanation given by Sam Leach is straight forward. Searching the web would send you well on your way to achieve this.

Comment: I have 8 different strings and all these needs to be read from this config file at runtime in the list view,where checkbox is set to true..Adding string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"] will add all the values of keys starting with 'key'?

Comment: @vysakh the key is unique (there can be only one with the same name). If you have 8 strings, you will have 8 appSettings entries in your app.config.